# Run Flask app with arguments in command line

Tags: python, flask, command-line-arguments

I have a flask app that works fine. However I need to include arguments when running the app in the command line. I can use `python app.py arg1` but when I try using `flask run arg1` it throws the error:

```
Error: Got unexpected extra argument (arg1)
```

Is there any way to add arguments to the `flask run` command?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `flask run` you could define your entrypoint like so

```py
import sys
from flask import Flask

if __name__ == '__main__':
  foo = sys.argv[1]  
  app = Flask(__name__)
  app.config['foo'] = foo
  app.run()
```

However, it's probably wiser to create a custom cli command to take arguments for you and start up the flask app.
Read more about custom cli commands [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/cli/#custom-commands).

Comment: It works fine. However, I want to use `flask run` because then I want to add `--port=5000` and such parameters as well.

Comment: You could make a more complex cli command by using the `argparse` module from the stdlib. It would allow you to specify parameters in the style of `--param <value>` and is relatively straightforward to use.

Comment: A lot of flask documentation uses app decorators (e.g., `@app.route('/')`. The code above makes app a local variable, so you can't use the decorators. Is there any way to allow the app decorators, or do you just have to call the functions in this style?